# Coefficient for the gradient term in stochastic gradient descent (SGD) with momentum

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I'm studying SGD with momentum and have come across two versions of the update formula.

The first is from a wiki:

```
dw = a * dw - lr * dL/dw # w: weights; lr: learning rate; dL/dw: drivatives of loss function over w
w := w + dw
```

The second version is more common:

```
dw = a * dw - (1 - a) * dL/dw
w := w + dw
```

My question is: why must the coefficient for the `dL/dw` term be `(1-a)`? It seems to me that even if `lr != (1 - a)`, this would still make sense.
Is there any specific reason to choose this coefficient?

I asked chatgpt and it tells me the first version is not correct but not providing any reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of the gradients `dL/dw` as a sequence of numbers, then idea of momentum is to keep track of a moving average of the sequence `dL/dw`, and step in the direction of this average, not in the direction of the actual gradient, which can be noisy since it is calculated from a single exmaple/ a small batch.

The formula `dw = a * dw + (1 - a) * dL/dw` represents a way to easily calculate the Exponential moving average (EMA) at each step. To answer your question: if the coefficient of the second term wasn't `(1-a)`, then the result can't sensibly be described as an *average*.

- A simple demonstration would be to check what happens if `dL/dw` is a constant sequence,

  - `(1-a)` implies `dw` will be constant and equal to `dL/dw`
  - anything else and `dw` will either converge to zero or diverge

If you want to alter the learning rate you should use:

```
dw = a * dw + (1 - a) * dL/dw
w := w - lr * dw
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Viewing `dw` as an Exponential Moving Average (EMA) offers an insightful perspective. 
From what I can gather, a conventional EMA takes the form of `dw = a * dw + (1 - a) * dL/dw` not `dw = a * dw - (1 - a) * dL/dw `. 
While I do agree that for `lr < (1-a)`, convergence to 0 is likely, this seems reasonable for various other learning rate selections as well. And I believe that when `lr < (1-a)`, divergence is possible (not necessarily), yet this issue is akin to overshooting.

Comment: As this question is closed, I reopen this on [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761231/coefficient-for-the-gradient-term-in-stochastic-gradient-descent-sgd-with-mome)

Comment: Oh right yes, definitely with a plus `+` not a `-`. (I copied it from your question without thinking) Can you link where have you seen it with a `-`?

Comment: Acctually the formation should be `dw = a * dw + (1 - a) * dL/dw` and `w := w - dw`. I made a little modification to facilitate a clear comparison between these two versions.